# How this TreeVisitor function works for this Binary Search Tree assignment

Tags: c++, function, binary-search-tree

I'm pretty new to C++, so apologies in advance for my limited understanding and also this being my first post on stackoverflow, I apologize for the formatting if it's wrong.

I'm working on an assignment that we are building a binary search tree. For the most part I understand how BST works. But the assignment had a couple of built in functions that I'm a bit confused on how they work. Conceptually I know how a BST works and how inorder is supposed to behave, but within the confines of utilizing these functions, I'm confused.

The most unusual thing to me is calling a function as an argument and the use of visit, which sounds like a built in standard function.

**What is treevisitor doing?**

**What am I storing in treevisitor?**

**What exactly is happening here: b1.InorderTraverse(TreeVisitor::visitor);? What is the argument being passed here, I assume a stringstream**

**What exactly is being built when InorderTraverse is being called? I would assume you would want to return something, but my assumption is something is being stored by the treevisitor to get the string result.**

Thank you in advance for any help provided and apologies if I was not concise enough with what I'm asking.

This is piece of code exists in a bst_test.cpp

```
class TreeVisitor {
public:
    TreeVisitor() = delete;

    // insert output to SS rather than cout, so we can test it
    static stringstream SS;

    static string GetSS() {
    return SS.str();
    }

    static void ResetSS() {
    SS.str(string());
    }
    // instead of cout, insert item into a string stream
    static void visitor(const string &item) {
    SS << item;
    }

    // instead of cout, insert item into a string stream
    static void visitor(const int &item) {
    SS << item;
    }
};
```

The bst_test.cpp given to use has this to test our inorderTraversal in main.cpp

```
TreeVisitor::ResetSS();
b1.InorderTraverse(TreeVisitor::visitor);
string result = "acfgx";
assert(TreeVisitor::GetSS() == result);
```

In our bst.hpp we have this, I've added some code and a helper method that is pulled out of our textbook.

```
// Public function
void InorderTraverse(void visit(const T &item)) const {
    inOrder(visit, rootPtr);
}


// Private Helper function
void inOrder(void visit(const T &item), Node* Ptr) const{
    if(Ptr != NULL){
        inOrder(visit, Ptr->leftPtr);
        T item = Ptr->data;
        visit(item);
        inOrder(visit, Ptr->rightPtr);
    }
}
```

I believe it all works because the assert statement doesn't kick back an error.

Comment: What is `b1`?  Looks like an object of some class.  [Edit] your question to include the definition of `b1` and its class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the deal with homework assignments, I forget...

Anyway:

What is treevisitor doing?

- TreeVisitor is a class that basically accumulates a string via a stringstream. It presents a 'visitor' method that, every time it gets called, adds the item to the string. This class doesn't traverse the tree at all, it just does something for a item (in this class add the string representation to the string). This gets used by the inOrder traversal, or any other traverser (and doesn't even have to be used on a tree).

What am I storing in treevisitor?

- you are storing a stringstream, which is accumulating a representation of all the items it encounters in sequence.

What exactly is happening here: b1.InorderTraverse(TreeVisitor::visitor);? What is the argument being passed here, I assume a stringstream

- That is passing the TreeVisitor's visitor method to the InorderTraverse method. InorderTraverse will then recursively traverse the tree, and call that method for every node it hits.

What exactly is being built when InorderTraverse is being called? I would assume you would want to return something, but my assumption is something is being stored by the treevisitor to get the string result.

- the TreeVisitor, again, is accumulating a string representation of the entire tree in traversal order. When the traversal is complete (every node has been hit), then the TreeVisitor::GetSS methods gets the final string.

Since this looks like homework, if I may: the interesting part of this to you is the 'in order traversal', which is recursively traversing the tree, and calling the given function on each node. It's designed this way so you can pass different functions, but the traversal is written once.

Comment: Sorry, buried in homework so my reply is quite late. But thank you for this great explanation! This is really helpful... and yeah...Homework... what's the deal? hah.

Comment: Odd I thought I commented this. Unfortunately, being a new user... my upvote doesn't count for anything... Perhaps I can come back and upvote once I get 15 reputation.

Comment: Ahh, apologies. Thought upvoting was the arrows!